# Beautiful Soup prettify format only string values

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am using Beautiful Soup 4 to parse and modify a couple of Angular templates (HTML files). I have some issues when using the `prettify` function to write the modified content back into the file. This issue is related to special characters such as: >, <, etc.

I need the HTML files to be formatted exactly as they were before the processing, without converting string values such as `&times;` to "×" and without converting attribute values such as `*ngIf="alarmCount > 0` to `*ngif="alarmCount &gt; 0`.

Below you have an example HTML template and the Beautiful Soup's output for each of the three built-in [output formatters](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#output-formatters) (html, minimal, None). Neither one does provide the desired output. There is also an option to pass a custom formatter function to prettify(), but since this custom formatter does not know if the string passed to it is an attribute value or a string value, I'm not sure if it's really helpful in this case.

Any suggestion in how to handle this is appreciated.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

test_html = """
<div id="someId" (window:resize)="sizeChanged($event)">
   <span *ngIf="alarmCount > 0">&times;</span>
</div>
"""

document = BeautifulSoup(test_html, "html.parser")
print(document.prettify(formatter="html"))
```

**Result with formatter="html":**

```
<div (window:resize)="sizeChanged($event)" id="someId">
 <span *ngif="alarmCount &gt; 0">
  &times;
 </span>
</div>
```

**Result with formatter=None:**

```
<div (window:resize)="sizeChanged($event)" id="someId">
 <span *ngif="alarmCount > 0">
  ×
 </span>
</div>
```

**Result with formatter="minimal":**

```
<div (window:resize)="sizeChanged($event)" id="someId">
 <span *ngif="alarmCount &gt; 0">
  ×
 </span>
</div>
```